# Getting averages of nested values - pre-calculate upon posting and store as fields or use aggregation function to filter and calculate them?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a REST server which is connected to mongoDB.
My DB has a collection with a bunch of tests in form like this:

```
{
  name: 'xxx',
  date: 'xxx',
  props: [
    {
      role: 1,
      commands: [
        {
          command: 'xxx',
          data: [
            {
              timestamp: 'xxx',
              cpu: 1,
              ram: 5
            },
            {
              timestamp: 'xxy',
              cpu: 2,
              ram: 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Collection is huge, or at least, has a potential to be.

`Props` - can contain up to 3 objects

`Props.commands` - can contain up to 30 objects

`Props.commands.data` - can contain up to 20 objects

Should I pre-calculate average values and store on each nested level or use aggregate function which Mongo offers to calculate them per need basis?

I tried using nested `$unwind's` for a single document and that already had a huge processing time, which makes sense given the amount of data.
I am wondering if it would be more sensible to simply store average values for each level when adding documents to the collection instead of calculating them after using the aggregation function of MongoDB.

End goal would be to filter out data using `$match`, then aggregate cpu and ram based on that, with the quickest method possible.

I am rather new to Mongo and therefore have a very limited experience with aggregation pipeline and capabilities, so any tips would be most welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: please add the result as well and what you have tried.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as too broad